# Can dm-verity will support authentication of Ubifs root file system in Linux

Tags: kernel, yocto, rootfs, yocto-layer, ubifs

I want to authenticate my root file system which is in Ubifs file type mounted on NAND flash device.

Will dm-verity will support ubifs file system ?

In dm-verity-img.bb class file i have seen only below file systems mentioned.

```
DM_VERITY_IMAGE = "core-image-full-cmdline" # or other image
DM_VERITY_IMAGE_TYPE = "ext4" # or ext2, ext3 & btrfs
IMAGE_CLASSES += "dm-verity-img"
```

Answer (score 0):

the mechanism for signing and verifying your software, using dm-verity, is called a "Merkel Tree". Within that approach, you are using **blocks** of data to create a hash tree of your data to protect. This tree in turn can be used fast at runtime to make integrity checks within the device mapper "on-the-fly". With on-the-fly I mean directly, when the data is accessed from user space in a way, where the performance of the system is not impacted.

That being said, dm-verity is working in connection with **block-oriented** filesystems, like ext4, squashfs, etc. UBIFS in turn is kind of a "special" filesystem, explicitly not characterized as block device. You can check e.g. https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/ubifs.html for reference.

Hence my understanding - also bolstered by an actual implementation in an embedded system, using both squashfs and UBIFS - is that you **cannot use dm-verity for UBIFS**.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please let me know which mechanism we can use to authentic UBIFS file system?

Comment: @cherry411: At least in the system, I am contributing to at the moment, we are using a proprietary mechanism. It includes some 3rd party checks on signatures at file level.
Even more important, there is a service, which can be run from user space and which creates a hash over all partitions, used in the system. Out of those hashes, some kind of "master hash" is created and compared to the hash, constructed at build time. You can incorporate signatures here as well again, if your shared images could be exploited.
I am afraid I cannot provide a fully functional, accessible solution.